# The title and image keep repeating in all pages

Tags: titles

I am trying to make a paper and it's my first time to use the Tex format. I got a design from another website and tried to modify it but the problem is that the title and an image next to it keeps showing in all pages.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=20mm,right=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm}
\usepackage{xcolor}    
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{flowfram,calc}
\newdynamicframe{\dimexpr.2\textwidth-.75\columnsep}{.3\textheight}{0pt}{.7\textheight}[upperfarleft]
\newdynamicframe{\dimexpr.3\textwidth-.75\columnsep}{.3\textheight}{.2\textwidth+.5\columnsep}{.7\textheight}[upperleft]
\newdynamicframe{\dimexpr.35\textwidth-.60\columnsep}{.3\textheight}{.5\textwidth+3\columnsep}{.69\textheight}[upperright]

\setdynamicframe*{upperleft}{style=raggedright}
\setdynamicframe*{upperright}{style=raggedleft}
\setdynamicframe*{upperfarleft}{style=centering}


\setlength{\columnsep}{20mm}
\setlength{\ffcolumnseprule}{3pt}
\twocolumninarea{\textwidth}{.7\textheight-5pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\ffruledeclarations}{\color[rgb]{0.9,0.9,0.9}}
\insertvrule{flow}{1}{flow}{2}

  \setdynamiccontents*{upperfarleft}{\includegraphics[height=7cm, width=9cm]{VirtualReality.jpg}}
  \setdynamiccontents*{upperleft}{}
  \setdynamiccontents*{upperright}{{\fontsize{47}{30}\selectfont \textbf{Virtual Reality Gaming} \break} ADNAN SALEH ALTENEIJI: Ibaraki University,         Graduate School Science and Information}

    \begin{document}

\thispagestyle{fancy}

 \textbf{Abstract}

 \section*{Introduction}

\clearpage

\textbf{Definition}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Out of interest, where did you find the example?

Comment: You just want a title right? No need to use package `flowfram`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do more or less what you were trying to achieve. A title for a twocolumn paper, with a light gray column separator. A bit of finetuning is still needed.

[image: aliTitle]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=20mm,right=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\tracingpatches
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@outputdblcol}{\normalcolor}{\color{black!40}}{}{}
\makeatother

\setlength{\columnseprule}{3pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20mm}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
        \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}%
        {\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image}}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}%
        \hfill\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\raggedleft\fontsize{47}{30}\bfseries
    Virtual Reality Gaming\medbreak}\par
    Adnan Saleh Alteneiji: Ibraki University, \par
    Graduate School Science and Information
\end{minipage}%
\end{minipage}%
\bigbreak
]

\noindent\textbf{Abstract}

\section*{Introduction}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what am trying to achieve. Thank you so much.